# Problem: .NET Performance counter data goes missing after a short period

Tags: .net, memory, perfmon

I am trying to log the .Net memory performance counters but the logs stop recording data after a bit. I am doing this for a bunch of servers and all of them stop working at different points in time. Here is the one I am logging .NET CLR Memory(w3wp)# Total reserved Bytes
But the other counters like vbytes etc. also show the same results.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue or has faced something similar and been able to resolve yet ?